# Elasticsearch match on contained phrase with whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch, search, tokenize

I need a search where there should be a search match if a key phrase is contained, but the key phrase can have whitespace and the whole phrase must be there.

The way I understand it, the `index_analyzer` and `searh_analyzer` can both either split on spaces or not, giving four possibilities - none of which seem to do what I need.

As an example, let's say the key phrase is "one to". That means I would like a search with "one two" or "one two three" to match but not one with "one". Considering the different options:

1. Split on both index and search -> doesn't work because "one" will match
2. Split on index but not on search -> doesn't work because "one two" won't match
3. Don't split on index, split on search -> doesn't work because "one two" won't match
4. Don't split on neither index nor search -> doesn't work because "one two three" won't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution might be to create new [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) for that field with type [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), then it won't be analyzed by `ElasticSearch` and would be stored "as is" (actually you can run normalizer against it if you need to process/change it in some way). Then you don't need to deal with analyzers.

Let's say you have field with name `description`, then mapping might looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "description": {
    "type": "text", // assuming you originally have it as text
    "fields": {
      "original": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 512 // You can skip or change it and ES applies default value. 
    }
  }
```

The above code means that `ElasticSearch` would keep two versions of message - default analyzed and new one which is not analyzed. Then you can access it in the following name: `description.original` and use for example wildcard search.